# How can i add a .lib file to my cmake project

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl

I'm new to cmake and trying to use a static library. The project currently has this structure:

```
SDLTest  
-->includes  
-->libs  
---->x86  
------>SDL2.lib  
-->CMakeLists.txt  
-->main.cpp
```

CMakeLists.txt contains

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project ("SDLTest")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "includes")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/x86/SDL2.lib")
```

It compiles without problems, but when I execute the program it tells me that the program can' start because SDL2.dll is missing.

How can I tell cmake to use the static SDL2.lib instead of SDL2.dll?

Comment: It looks like that `SDL2.lib` file which you have is NOT a *static* library, but a **definition** file for a *dynamic* library. This would explain why `.dll` is needed when run the program.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the dynamic library `SDL2.dll` in the same folder of your program in addition to link with the static library.

In order to use *only* an static library, you'll have to compile it from source, [according to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9105714/1335511).